# jQuery and IIS 7.5 not working

Tags: jquery, iis

I have a problem with an asp.net project: when run in local, all goes well, but on a Windows Server 2008 R2, IIS 7.5, I'm unable to use jQuery scripts: the browers don't execute anything related to the script.
I have this script in an aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/FoamQuinflex.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="dettaglioOrdine.aspx.cs" Inherits="FoamQuinflex.dettaglioOrdine1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function mostraMessaggio(messaggio) {
            alert(messaggio);
        }


        function TotaliOrdDett() {



            var tBox;
            var i;
            var grid;
            var sumQta;
            var sumKg;

            sumQta = 0;
            sumKg = 0;

            grid = document.getElementById("<%=DettOrdGridView.ClientID%>");
            tBox = grid.getElementsByTagName("input");

            for (i = 0; i < tBox.length ; i++) {
                //alert("tBox.name: " + tBox[i].name);
                //alert("tBox.name: " + tBox[i].getAttribute("nomeTextBox"));
                if (tBox[i].getAttribute("nomeTextBox") == "myTextBoxQta") {
                    if (!isNaN(parseInt(tBox[i].value)))
                        sumQta += parseInt(tBox[i].value);
                }
                else if (tBox[i].getAttribute("nomeTextBox") == "myTextBoxKgNetti") {
                    if (!isNaN(parseInt(tBox[i].value)))
                        sumKg += parseFloat(tBox[i].value.replace(",", "."));
                }
            }



            document.getElementById("<%=txtSumQta.ClientID%>").innerText = sumQta.toFixed(2);
            document.getElementById("<%=txtSumKg.ClientID%>").innerText = sumKg.toFixed(2);



        }


        //Quando il documento è stato caricato...
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var txtSumKgDec;

            //Se il totale Kg netti non ha decimali, o ne ha solo uno, riempie con zeri i decimali mancanti.
            //Questo per uniformità con le altre visualizzazioni decimali.
            txtSumKgDec = $("#<%= txtSumKg.ClientID %>").val();
            $("#<%= txtSumKg.ClientID %>").val(parseFloat(txtSumKgDec).toFixed(2));
            //************************************************************************************
            //Controlla i valori immessi nel caso di salvataggio provvisorio
            $("#btnSaveProvvisorio").on("click", function (e) {
                var i;
                var jElemento;
                var boolEsito;
                var temp;




                //Questa function controlla se la quantità espressa in numero pezzi è numerica, se è positiva e senza decimali.
                $('.cssQta').each(function (i, v) {
                    jElemento = $(this).val();
                    if (jElemento) {
                        if (isNaN(jElemento)) {
                            alert("Attenzione: " + jElemento + " non è un numero!");
                            e.preventDefault();
                            return (false);
                        }
                        else
                            if (parseInt(jElemento < 0)) {
                                alert("Attenzione: " + jElemento + " è negativo!");
                                e.preventDefault();
                                return (false);
                            }
                            else
...
```

and a master page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="FoamQuinflex.master.cs" Inherits="FoamQuinflex.FoamQuinflex1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Login Orsa foam - Quinflex</title>
    <script src='<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js") %>' type="text/javascript"></script>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {
            text-align: center;
        }
        .auto-style2 {
            color: #5D7B9D;
            background-color: #F7F6F3;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManagerMasterPage" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    ...
```

the site structure is:
root/foamquinflex/
and the scripts directory containing the jquery sources is:
root/foamquinflex/Scripts
Where is the problem?
Thanks a lot!
Igor

Comment: Is jQuery getting loaded?

Comment: Check the javascript console and network tab of your browser's dev tools for errors.

Comment: the fact that you are using IIS over some other webserver should make no difference when it comes to client-side code. With that in mind, view the source of the page and find where the javascript was outputted. Include that in your question. Chances are ASP isn't outputting what you expect it to.

Comment: It seems that the $(document).ready(function () doesn't work; it does not enter in the function of document ready!

Comment: I debug the application and I discovered that with Firefox and Chrome the scripts are executed; the problem persists with Internet Explorer 11!